# Ubuntu 18.04 - root filesystem full

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage

My root filesystem is full.  how can I fix the problem?  I allocated 15G to root which I understand should be sufficient, I wonder if I have configured the partitions correctly.  there might be a problem with the /snap directory.

Here is the output of selected commands:

**`df -h /`**

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2   15G   13G  498M  97% /
```

**`df -h`**

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.1M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   15G   13G  498M  97% /
tmpfs            16G  4.0M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5662
/dev/loop1      173M  173M     0 100% /snap/spotify/21
/dev/loop2       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop7       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop3       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop4      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop6       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop8      174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/24
/dev/loop10     130M  130M     0 100% /snap/postman/73
/dev/loop9      484M  484M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/90
/dev/loop11      18M   18M     0 100% /snap/pdftk/9
/dev/loop12      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop13     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop15     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/222
/dev/loop14      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop16      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop17     174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/26
/dev/loop18     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop20     479M  479M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/86
/dev/loop19      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/808
/dev/loop21     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop22      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop23     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop24      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop26     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop25     479M  479M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/85
/dev/loop27      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/sda1       1.8T  434G  1.3T  25% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p4  215G   61M  204G   1% /m2
/dev/nvme0n1p1  975M  6.1M  968M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G   16K  3.2G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           3.2G   36K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

**`sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | grep '[0-9]G\>'`**

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | grep '[0-9]G\>'
434G    /home
11G /snap
4.2G    /usr
2.0G    /tmp
5.6G    /var
du: cannot access '/proc/7893/task/7893/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/7893/task/7893/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/7893/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/7893/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
459G    /
```

**`dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n`** (an alternative could be `wajig sizes | tail -30`)

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
[snip]
132042  libreoffice-core
134299  libgl1-mesa-dri
147486  libgl1-mesa-dri
161309  thunderbird
166969  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
166997  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic
167001  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic
167039  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic
174305  firefox
179065  openjdk-11-jre-headless
194447  google-chrome-stable
236804  zoom
271127  linux-firmware
```

here are some things that I already tried, they didn't help:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic # for old versions

sudo find / -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -prune

$ dpkg -l "linux*{tools}*" |grep ^.i
dpkg-query: no packages found matching linux*{tools}*
```

I would be grateful for any assistance.

**Edit**:  this is how my drive appears in `gparted`:

[image: screenshot]

So it looks like I have a 256G m2 drive and i installed the boot, root, and swap partitions there, with leftover space mounted at /m2.  my /home directory is on a separate device.

So if I can't fix whatever is wrong with root, I'm wondering if I could increase its size by 1) delete /m2 2) delete swap 3) resize root 4) recreate swap. Would that work?

**Edit #2**:

**`du -h /var/lib/snapd/snaps`**

```
$ du -h /var/lib/snapd/snaps
4.0K    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/partial
2.8G    /var/lib/snapd/snaps
```

Comment: Your snap apps are using 11GB, that's where the problem lies. These are the apps installed via Ubuntu Store. Currently, it is using the storage from your root partition.

Comment: Check the compressed snap usage at */var/lib/snapd/snaps* to see if the actual storage is taking up a lot of the root partition.

Comment: many thanks for getting back to me.  i edited my post to show the output of "du -h /var/lib/snapd/snaps".  how should i fix the problem?

Comment: could i fix it by mounting /var elsewhere?  my /home directory is mounted on a different disk with loads of free space, could i mount /var there?

Comment: just a FYI: 15gb is enough only if you don't install many programs, as you require a lot of space to release-upgrade to the next version (unless your plan is nuke & install [clean]), the current wiki recommendation is 25gb.

Comment: Yes you can install any directory elsewhere (assuming that mount isn't encrypted differently (as /home can be decrypted later thus boot problems as it's not available), Using 'live' media you can `cp -pr` it there, modify your `fstab` to mount it, then boot & verify it works.   Only if happy would I actually delete the original directory (from live) -- but note this will cause headaches if you have problems in the future (you'll likely forget it if you need to `chroot` into the partition to fix things etc.. or next release-upgrade`).  My choice would be expand the partition (shrink /home)

Comment: The 2.8G of compressed snap in 5.6G of var doesn't seem unreasonable. Something else is using quite a bit of spaces in var. May be lot of log files, transmission daemon files or your apt cache stuff. Try getting rid of other stuff that is clogging up the /var. Also, 2G in tmp usage seems a lot.

Comment: As a stopgap measure you can likely copy `/snap` to your `/m2` filesystem and add a soft link to it in `/`. Increasing the partition size is doable (much easier/safer than shrinking it), but since your own data is on another device, repartitioning and reinstalling could also be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a 256GB M2 drive on which i had installed boot, root, and swap, with leftover space mounted under /m2.  then i have a 1TB drive on which i installed /home.  snap filled up my /var directory.

i think the correct solution would have been to move /var to /home/var but i couldn't get that to work.

then i zapped swap and /m2, increased the size of root, and added back swap and /m2.  but then i got errors relating to invalid sectors or corrupt disk, i can't remember exactly.

so then i stopped using the M2 drive altogether.  i tried to shrink /home and to put boot, root, and swap at the end of the 1TB drive.  but this got corrupted too.  in the end i did a bare metal reinstall to the 1TB drive.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live distro, shrink p4 partition, move p3 next to p4, resize  p2