# Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS root directory full

Tags: 18.04, directory, root, lts

Few weeks ago my Nextcloud is not working and I start to troubleshoot the issue but still no luck.  Finally i decided to reinstall my Nextcloud after I removed the PHP, I suddenly discover my root directory is full.

I have face the / full issue several time in the last two year after I upgraded to 18.04 LTS.

I am not sure whether it is related to my Nextcloud or not, however the Nextcloud is not working for few week and I try to expand my vg partition from 21G, to 31G, then to 41G, finally to 81G but still getting / full over the night.

I google many similar discussion about the reason of / full, such as:

- search which files/directory under / occupied the largest disk space
- check mariadb log
- check system log
- clean up old kernal and unused package etc.

eg: similar issue: [Ubuntu 18.04 - root filesystem full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097509/ubuntu-18-04-root-filesystem-full)

However I follow all instruction there but still can't found what's the root cause.

Follow is the directory info:

```
# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        382M  3.7M  379M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/server--vg-root   81G   80G     0 100% /
/dev/mapper/server--vg-usr   4.5G  2.2G  2.1G  52% /usr
tmpfs                        1.9G  1.4M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdd1                    3.6T  2.8T  707G  80% /mnt/extDisk1
/dev/sdb1                    3.6T  901G  2.6T  26% /mnt/extDisk2
/dev/sde1                    3.6T  1.8T  1.7T  52% /mnt/extDisk3
/dev/sda1                    1.8T  1.7T   61G  97% /mnt/extDisk4
/dev/mapper/server--vg-srv   9.2G   22M  8.7G   1% /srv
/dev/mapper/server--vg-boot  1.9G   89M  1.7G   5% /boot
/dev/mapper/server--vg-var    19G  6.5G   12G  36% /var
/dev/mapper/server--vg-home  4.5G  293M  4.0G   7% /home
/dev/sdf1                    236M  6.4M  217M   3% /mnt/extDisk5
/dev/mapper/server--vg-tmp   4.5G  9.5M  4.3G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/server--vg-opt   4.5G  238M  4.0G   6% /opt
tmpfs                        382M     0  382M   0% /run/user/997
tmpfs                        382M     0  382M   0% /run/user/500
```

```
# sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | grep '[0-9]G\>'
2.2G    /usr
6.4G    /var
du: cannot access '/proc/6813/task/6813/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/6813/task/6813/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/6813/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/6813/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
#
```

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
[snip]
9665    libapache2-mod-php5
9976    texlive-latex-base
10176   libqt5gui5
10479   python3.7-minimal
10756   fonts-lmodern
10996   samba
11224   libx265-146
11714   binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu
11877   libc6
12064   grub-common
12067   librados2
12219   poppler-data
12396   python3-twisted
12524   systemd
12741   linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic
12834   linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic
12975   python-twisted-core
13439   libavcodec57
13644   libgcc-7-dev
14128   locales
14359   python-samba
14816   postgresql-10
15276   libfftw3-dev
15352   libstdc++-7-dev
15393   doxygen
16134   perl-modules
16347   libgs9
17049   libperl-dev
18232   texlive-fonts-recommended
18501   perl-modules-5.26
18648   iso-codes
18812   libc6-dev
18995   libimage-exiftool-perl
19640   resilio-sync
20238   texlive-pictures
20359   libperl5.22
20754   humanity-icon-theme
21395   libperl5.26
22287   samba-libs
24009   cpp-7
24033   mariadb-client-10.4
25433   texlive-extra-utils
26062   g++-7
26227   libllvm3.4
27284   libicu52
27325   gcc-7
27399   libclang1-6.0
27483   libflite1
28420   vim-runtime
30517   texlive-latex-recommended
31074   libicu60
31508   git
32496   libicu65
35889   mesa-vdpau-drivers
40596   libpython2.7-dev
43986   linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic
44508   linux-image-3.16.0-77-generic
49042   texlive-latex-extra
51916   texlive-base
54208   openjdk-7-jre-headless
59703   libllvm6.0
63258   linux-modules-4.15.0-45-generic
63362   linux-modules-4.15.0-70-generic
63539   linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic
63763   linux-modules-4.15.0-101-generic
66442   linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic
67746   libllvm9
72860   imagemagick-7.0.8
74249   linux-headers-4.15.0-72
74358   mariadb-server-10.1
74384   linux-headers-4.15.0-101
76061   mariadb-server-10.4
98266   openjdk-8-jre-headless
152499  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic
152546  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic
152791  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-77-generic
165608  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic
165684  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-101-generic
167065  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic
170524  webmin
221877  emby-server
232263  libgl1-mesa-dri
324978  linux-firmware
#
```

And follow the same I already tried, they didn't help too:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic # for old versions

sudo find / -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -prune

$ dpkg -l "linux*{tools}*" |grep ^.i
dpkg-query: no packages found matching linux*{tools}*
```

Anyone expert could give me some hits on how to solve this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Since you already read similar discussions: What is consuming 80G in your root (/) ?

Comment: I try to some command to search some large file, eg. larger then 1G (I didn't remark down the command while I google).  However there is no big file under the /. This is the reason I can't sort out what's consumed my root direct.

Comment: I am sure that some of the questions/answers you have read, suggested using `du` to work out where the space  in the root-filesystem has gone. Start by `du -sh /*`  find the largest directories and look at them, probably /var/log.

Comment: @SorenA thanks for your advise, however, my /var is mapped in separate vg partition (detail df shows above):

/dev/mapper/server--vg-var    19G  6.5G   12G  36% /var